# How to efficiently remove empty Excel rows using VBS?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to remove the whole row IF `column A` value is empty. I have been doing it in excel and this method works best for me

`.Columns("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

I need to do the same thing using `vbs` however, I have issues converting it to vbs

How can I convert the above line into vbs?

I looked up the `xlCellTypeBlanks = 4` using `F2` . But how to use the `SpecialCells` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4

Dim xlApp
Dim xlwb

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xlApp.workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsm")
On Error Resume Next
xlwb.Sheets(1).Columns("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an object for the Excel App, Workbook, Worksheet etc.. So something like

```
Dim xlApp as Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wb as object
Set wb = xlApp.Open("YourWorbookName.xlsx")
wb.Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet").Columns("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Of course I do have an object for all of the above. It is just this line `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).` that does not compile in `vbs`

Comment: Add `Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4`